# Selection Changed Event in TreeviewUsing Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have one doubt i doing one delphi application.If i select the treeview node at run time display the form in every selected nodes.how its work?.please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow, in order to get answers please elaborate better your question.

Comment: do you want to display a form on selecting a treeview node? @RRUZ liked your way

Comment: Sounds like you just need to handle the [`OnChange`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnChange) event.

Answer (score 1):

In Tree View Component, Every node was represented by TTreeNode object, this object has index of selected node, text, etc..

If you want to show form for every node double click 
just add the following code

```
if Treeview1.Selected.Text = 'first_form' then
    begin
      TFirst_Form.create(Application)
      TFirst_Form.show
    end;
```